# How to scroll to the top of a modal window in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is that I need to show a modal window as a form to be filled by user. But the height of that modal should be not more then window size.

So if the entries in form are too much then the modal becomes scrollable. The problem is that while validating the entries in the form the error message is shown at the top of the modal above the first entry. If user is at last property then he will not be knowing that some validation error had occurred unless the modal is scrolled to top on the error event.

I have tried :

```
$(window).scrollTop();
// and
$('#modalId').scrollTop();
```

this is the modal code:

```
<div class="modal hide" id="groupModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: 300px;">
        <div class="grpForm">
            <div class="alert alert-error hide">

                <span class="errMsg"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success hide">

                <span class="successMsg"></span>
            </div>
            <form class = "formFieldHolder" id="groupInfoForm"></form>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn cancelFormBtn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" msgkey="common.cancel.label"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary submitGroupFormBtn" type="submit" msgkey="common.submit.label"></button>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your modal window code

Comment: i don't know how to I just copy pasted html but that didn't displayed on the question content So i just reverted the code. Let me see FAQ and will post the code when I know how to. Might take time b'coz have to work on something now.

Comment: You can post code by paste the code and select and then click `{}` icon

Comment: Thank you @Chamika this is first time I am asking question which needed code since I created profile

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`$('#modalId').scrollTop(0);`

`scrollTop()` only returns the value; `scrollTop(0)` sets the value to 0 (all the way to the top)

Comment: Thank you very much on the explanation of difference between the above two. However I achieved what I wanted, initially I was using the the $('#modalId').scrollTop(0); but instead of this I was supposed to do $('#bodyId_within_modal_which_is_scrollabe').scrollTop(0);

Answer (score 13):

To scroll the page to the modal, select `html, body` and scroll to the offset top of the modal

```
$("html, body").scrollTop($("#modalId").offset().top);
```

If you want to scroll the modal div to the top use

```
$("#modalId").scrollTop(0);
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhjFq/)

You can combine both to scroll the page and the modal to a visible area for the user if needed.

**References**

- [jQuery scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)
- [jQuery offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: This will scroll the page to the top of modal window. but he want to scroll the content of modal

Comment: Yes as said above this took me to top of modal window. Direct use of scrollTop(0) is best solution as far unless it has some back-end complications. Thanks for answering though this might be helpful somewhere else .

Answer (score 11):

This is a solution without using JQuery, first you get your modal by the id and then, the function [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) will move to the top of the element you selected, in this case your modal.

```
let element = document.getElementById('groupModal');    
element.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: While a snippet is fine, could you please elaborate *how* and *why* this solves the OPs issue?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid rough movement to the top I would prefer to use (animated movement):

```
$('#modalId').animate({
        scrollTop : 0
    }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('.scroll_top').hide();
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('.scroll_top').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('.scroll_top').fadeOut();
                }
            }); 

            $('.scroll_top').click(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
                return false;
            });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to include "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" file in your page.
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js